# What's wrong with this question? Why was it closed?

Tags: discussion

[What determines if the XP/2000-style file picker uses the XP-styles icons on toolbar or 2000-style icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75904026/what-determines-if-the-xp-2000-style-file-picker-uses-the-xp-styles-icons-on-too)

The closing message says it is not about programming, but in fact I want to know how to call the FileOpenDialog so it to have Win-2000 style icons or whether it is determined by manifest file. Please re-open this question, it is legitimate.

P.S. I expanded the question with more context.

Comment: You have some code that displays one style but you want to change that code to display the other style?

Comment: @RobertLongson I want to write a Windhawk mod that would do it in all apps.

Comment: The way it's worded at the moment could, in my opinion, easily be mistaken to be read like you're asking about how an application works, not how you would replicate that behaviour in *your own* application. Add the title, which *does* read like that, and you can see why it was voted as not about programming.

Comment: @ThomA I have to know how this works in different applications. So far, in all programs the icons are XP-style except in LibreOffice and Free MP3 Sound Recorder. I wonder what sets them apart. My aim is to make a Winhawk mod that would make all apps like LibreOffice and Free MP3 Sound Recorder

Comment: You make no mention of wanting to make some kind of mod on your question, @Anixx . In truth, you need to completely reword the question to explain what you are really asking. You don't even tag a language in the question, so we don't even know what (from the question alone) what tools you are going to be using to try and get the behaviour in your own application.

Comment: @RobertLongson WindHawk mods are written in C++. If it is not programming, then what is?

Comment: So why isn't your question tagged with [[tag:c++]], @Anixx ? Why does it make *no reference* to Windhawk?

Comment: @ThomA I do not know in what languages those programs are written. Maybe the style of the dialog depends on the programming language. But I just tagged it with C++.

Comment: What language the application(s) you want to mod is written in is irrelvant, @Anixx . You tag the language you are writing in.

Answer (score 16):

Everything was wrong with the first revision of your question.

Its title said: "What determines if the XP/2000-style file picker uses the XP-styles icons on toolbar or 2000-style icons?"

The body said: "What determines if the XP/2000-style file picker uses the XP-styles icons on toolbar or 2000-style icons?" accompanied with a screenshot.

And the tags were: [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [filepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filepicker)

For starters: Do not copy the title verbatim in the body and call it a day. Even not when decorated with an image.

From [What is on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

> The best Stack Overflow questions generally have a bit of source code in them

There is nothing in the title, body or tags that suggests this is a programming issue. And if it is, it lacks any hint what kind of answer you expect. A link to the documentation of the WIN32 Dialog struct? Historical coffee table facts? A registry hack? A manifest hack? Compat Layer? A bootleg version of Windows 2000 so you can experience the dialog for real?

You had I don't know how many hours to gather all that info before you posted that question but after you posted you had another two hours before a moderator stumbled on your question and did The Right Thing™.

After closure you edited the question as pointed out in the close banner to make it a bit more answerable and by my (low) standards no longer close worthy. I have gone ahead and casted a re-open vote. I assume the actual SME will either follow my vote or prove I'm wrong.

Going forward I suggest you re-visit all the guidance we have in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and put a bit more effort in upfront instead of after fact where you then have to deal with both meta and your closed question.

Let me point out as well that with Stack Overflow we build a knowledge base for visitors to come. Your question can't for that reason just be a conversation starter where you and the community iteratively work out what you're dealing with. Questions have to be clear, focused and in scope right of the bat. If not, close and/or downvotes are used to signal the below par content.

Comment: "A registry hack? A manifest hack? Compat Layer?" - I actally do not know, the very question is to find out what makes different programs to display the dialog differently. The difference may be in code, but may be not.

Comment: @Anixx do you have written code or are you planning on changing the code you have shown in your question? If no, your question is off-topic. Is that code in your question a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) aka if I plug that into a C++ compiler does it show me a dialog that is in a modern era dialog style? If no, make sure it does. If yes, and I provide a change to your code to make it a show a Win95 dialog will that solve your issue? If no, why not? The answers to all these needs to go into your question, not in comments on a meta answer.

Answer (score 8):

At the time the question was closed, it didn't appear to be about programming. The title, to start with, is a poor introduction:

> What determines if the XP/2000-style file picker uses the XP-styles icons on toolbar or 2000-style icons?

This very much reads like you are asking how an *existing* application works, rather than how to do some *programming* related problem.

The question itself only seemed to reinforce that, as the *entire* contents at the time of the closure was:

> What determines if the XP/2000-style file picker uses the XP-styles icons on toolbar or 2000-style icons?
>
> [image]

There is *literally* nothing about programming there, as you just repeat the title and just add a picture; that alone doesn't make it a good question. The question was only tagged with [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [filepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filepicker), nothing else. The information, now informed to us in the comments of *this* question, that you want to use Windhawk to create a mod for programs was *compleletely* omitted.

---

The question as it is now, however, does appear to be more on topic. and has already been voted to be reopened.

Comment: I actually do not know if the dialog's icons' style is determined in the program's code or in manifest file, compat layer or somewhere else. It could be that it is determined in the code, I was unsure, that's why I asked it in the question...